How to put checking for more whitespaces in a negative look beyond?
I am creating a small function, which is capable of modifying the two lines below
 precision highp float; 
 highp float intensity;

to this:
 precision highp float; 
 lowp float intensity;

So practically I don't wanna modify the default precision modifier. I also would like to take into consideration what if there are whitespaces between precision and highp, like this:
 precision /*more white spaces*/ highp float;

I wanted to write \s+ into the look beyond part of the regex
  ((?<!\bprecision\s+)(highp\s+float))

but as far as I know boost negative look beyond does not support this and that is why it throws a runtime error to me.
What could be the solution?

An alternative to Wiktor's answer using just a neg. lookahead could be: If there is a word preceding highp... with one or more \s in between, use a neg. lookahead to check it is not the disallowed word. Else there must only be start of the string or a non-word-boundary (no spaces) - capture this part to the first group... Eg. replace (\b(?!precision\b)\w+\s+|^\s*|\B)highp\s+float with $1lowp float. This is certainly less efficient but supposed to work as well.

You can use
\bprecision\s+highp\s+float(*SKIP)(?!)|highp\s+float

See the regex demo.
The idea is to match the unwanted part of the string and skip it, and only then match what you need in other contexts.
Details

\bprecision\s+highp\s+float(*SKIP)(?!) - matches and then skips the following:

\b - word boundary
precision\s+highp\s+float - precision highp float with any amount of whitespaces between the words
(*SKIP)(?!) - omit the match from the match memory buffer and start looking for a match from the failure end position


| - or
highp\s+float - highp + one or more whitespaces + float.

Also, see more about (*SKIP) and other PCRE verb support in Boost.
Note that (*FAIL) = (?!).
You can also search for \bprecision\s+highp\s+float(*SKIP)(?!)|highp(?=\s+float) and replace with just lowp.
Add word boundaries where necessary.
